# Having issue with Jersey query params

Tags: java, jersey

I'm new to Java. I'm trying to understand Jersey API and to make my command line application to use Jersey in order to query some information. When I'm passing a string as a query, it just throws an exception cause there is some white space in the query that I have passed. Could anyone help me with passing sentence as query and I also need to return the same query as my response text and explanation of how it can be done with multiple ways if there the efficient one, so that I could understand the code.

Here is my main class that passes the query:

```java
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("enter : ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String query = sc.nextLine();
        URL obj = new URL("http://localhost:8080/Sample/api/newstring/next?query="+query);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "plain/text");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println(reader.readLine());
    }
}
```

Here is my API:

```java
@Path("newstring")
public class ApiCall{
       @GET
       @Path("next")
       @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
       public String grtMethod(@QueryParam("query")String a){
              return a;
       }

}
```

Comment: urlencode the query string

Comment: Use `"[..]?query=" + URLEncoder.encode(query, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`, or use a suitable URL builder that does the necessary encoding for you.